# Programatically update field/column name in a list on all sub sites [Powershell]

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, content-type

What I want to do is with a Powershell script programatically go through all subsites in a site collection and change a column name in a list from  "Web" to "Site".

So in easier words:
Go through subsites 1 2 3 4 5 6...
Change a column name "Web" in a list to "Site".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'} 

if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{    
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"    
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"  -EA SilentlyContinue
}

$site = Get-SPSite http://portal

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $lists = $web.Lists

    foreach ($list in $lists)
    {
        foreach ($column in $list.Fields)
        {
            if ($column.Title -eq "Web")
            {
                $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true
                Write-Host "Before change: " $web.Title
                $web.Title = "Site"
                $web.Update()
                Write-Host " After change: " $web.Title
                $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false
                $web.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}

$site.Dispose()
```